# Fortigate monitoring with SNMP and Devmon template

Tags: firewalls, monitoring

I'm trying to monitor some aspects from our Fortigate firewall (like how many traffic goes through each tunnel) through a combination of Xymon, Devmon and SNMP.

I downloaded the MIB files from the Fortinet site and managed to extract some values. However, it seems quite time absorbing to insert all this info manually in my Devmon config files.

So the question is: aren't there any default templates that you can download which center the important stuff?

For instance the CPU. You can have the CPU user percentage (very useful), the type (useful) or the packets received by a processor (useful, but is not supported by every processor). If I have to go through every entry in the two MIB files, then I'm not done by the new year.